# Transfer PDF from OS X to iPad

Tags: macos

I download pdf files on my Mac, and often transfer them to iPad to read.

This used to be straightforward, but the process seems to be much more complex.

I need to select the pdf, select "Open in iBooks" (which actually displays in Preview) then go through the process on iTunes to transfer it to iPad.

Is there a simpler way. I don't actually want to read in iBooks on the Mac (which doesn't happen anyway)?

All I really want to do is transfer selected pdf to iPad.

Comment: What generation are your devices?

Comment: Email them to yourself.

Comment: Why not Airdrop?

Answer (score 1):

Use cloud storage like Dropbox, iCloud drive, or Google Drive and put your PDF files on it. I personally read and highlight Pdf files on an iPad app called GoodReader. With the app I can sync my highlight between Mac and iPad. The highlight from GoodReader shows on Mac OS X' Preview app without a problem, unlike Adobe Reader on iPad. If you read a lot of PDF then GoodReader is a worthwhile little investment.

Comment: I really don't understand iCloud. Why would I download from email, just so I can upload, then download on another device, when I am going to delete it in a few days, and my devices are already directly connected by cable.

Comment: If the PDFs are already in your email, can you not simply access that email account from your iPad? If this is an ongoing thing that you want to do, it seems like that would be the most straightforward solution.

Comment: In iPad you can't easily copy files to and from iPad without iTunes. Can since you said going through the iTunes things is a trouble, then cloud drive solution is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

If your Mac is from 2012 or later with Yosemite, and your iPad is 4th generation, Air, or Air 2, then you can use AirDrop. Select the PDF in Finder, click AirDrop from the Share menu, and if your devices are on the same wifi network and have Bluetooth turned on, then you should see your iPad on the list of devices that you can send the PDF to.

---

If your devices don't meet the system requirements, or if what I described above doesn't work for any reason, plenty of 3rd-party solutions exist. My personal favorite is [DeskConnect](http://deskconnect.com).

Comment: I just read that DeskConnect will be discontinued.  The web page lists these as alternatives: AirDrop,
Handoff,
Instashare,
Universal Clipboard,

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use any iOS PDF reader or File Manager to transfer them via cable & iTunes. Good Reader or PDF Expert are one of the market leaders for PDF Viewers, both supporting [iTunes file sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201301) & using custom PDF viewers (support different types of annotations, bookmarks, etc.) 
Among the free alternatives, using standard iOS PDF viewer, I'd choose Documents by Readdle. Here's how it looks:

In short:

- Connect iPhone, Launch iTunes
- Select device icon at the top bar
- Choose File Sharing
- Tap on the app icon you picked to be the file manager
- Simply drag PDFs there